# Color of line in TabBar Qt QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

How can I change the color of the line that highlites the selected tab in the `TabBar`?

[image]

Comment: `import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0` and then `TabBar { Material.accent: Material.Red }`

Comment: ^^^ this should be an answer

Answer (score 2):

According to [@jpnurmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4666542/jpnurmi)'s comment, the best and easiest solution here is to utilize [`QtQuick.Controls.Material`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-material.html):

```
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
```

and then you can set [`Material.accent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-material.html#material-accent-attached-prop) for `TabBar`:

```
TabBar { 
  Material.accent: Material.Red 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the `TabBar`.
See the documentation:

> - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-tabbar
> - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-tabbutton
> - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-button

As it is written there, the `TabButton`s have a `background` and a `contentItem`.
You can assign your own delegates to those properties as seen in the documentation example. In your case you probably need a tailored `Rectangle` as `background`.

You can use the different properties of the `TabButton` to define styles for all their states.